# Choose at runtime which CRTP implementation to use

Tags: c++, crtp

I would like to use static polymorphism using the CRTP idiom while being able to choose at runtime which implementation to use. Let me take an example:

I have some classes responsible for computing stuff:

```
template<typename Implementation>
class FooInterface {
public:
  void compute(){
    (static_cast<Implementation*>(this))->compute();
  }
};

class FooForward : public FooInterface<FooForward> {
public:
  void compute(){
    //do stuff
  }
};

class FooBackward : public FooInterface<FooBackward> {
public:
  void compute(){
    //do other stuff
  }
};
```

and

```
template<typename Implementation>
class BarInterface {
public:
  void eval(){
    (static_cast<Implementation*>(this))->eval();
  }
};

class BarForward : public BarInterface<BarForward> {
public:
  void eval(){
    //do something
  }
};

class BarBackward : public BarInterface<BarBackward> {
public:
  void eval(){
    //do something else
  }
};
```

Now I want to use these objects as members of another class, let's call it `Model`, and use them in a loop:

```
template<typename Foo, typename Bar>
class Model {
private:
  Foo* foo_;
  Bar* bar_;
  int max_iter_;

public:
  Model<Foo, Bar>(int max_iter) : max_iter_(max_iter){
    foo_ = new Foo();
    bar_ = new Bar();
  }

  void solve(){
    for(int i = 0; i < max_iter_; ++i){
      foo_->compute();
      bar_->eval();
    }
  }
};
```

Note that the function `Model::solve()` performs a high number of iterations and performance in my application is critical, hence the use of CRTP instead of dynamic polymorphism to avoid virtual function calls and enable inlining of the functions by the compiler.

Now my problem arises when I want to let the user decide which implementation of `FooInterface` and `BarInterface` to use at runtime. In my `main.cpp` I have:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  /*
   * Here an input file is read into a map which looks like this
   * std::map<std::string, std::string> settings
   */
  // Here I need a way to choose, based on settings, what will Foo and Bar be
  Model<Foo, Bar> model;
  model.solve();
}
```

I have thought about a kind of factory that could return the correct `Model` but I don't know what the return type could be, and the way I imagine it is not convenient because in my application I have more than 2 template parameters and then the number of combinations becomes very large

```
class Factory{
  /*type?*/ createModel(std::map<std::string, std::string> settings){
    if ((settings["foo"] == "fwd") && (settings["bar"] == "fwd")){
      Model<FooForward, BarForward>* model = new Model<FooForward, BarForward>();
      return model;
    }
    else if ((settings["foo"] == "fwd") && (settings["bar"] == "bwd")){
      Model<FooForward, BarBackward>* model = new Model<FooForward, BarBackward>();
      return model;
    }
    else if ((settings["foo"] == "bwd") && (settings["bar"] == "fwd")){
      Model<FooBackward, BarForward>* model = new Model<FooBackward, BarForward>();
      return model;
    }
    else {
      Model<FooBackward, BarBackward>* model = new Model<FooBackward, BarBackward>();
      return model;
    }
  }
};
```

The way I imagine things, all the template combinations would be compiled and the user could choose at runtime which one to use. Is there a way to accomplish this using CRTP ?

Answer (score 4):

As to the factory method, I think there's no way to define a single type, as type information is needed during compile time and the actual settings will be only known during program execution.

But if you make use of a variant, it's possible to combine all possible return types into a single one. This type can then be returned by the factory method:

```
class Factory{

public:

    using ModelVariant = boost::variant
    <
        Model< FooBackward , BarBackward > ,
        Model< FooBackward , BarForward > ,
        Model< FooForward , BarBackward > ,
        Model< FooForward , BarForward >
    >;

    static ModelVariant createModel(std::map<std::string, std::string> settings , int i)
    {
        if ((settings["foo"] == "fwd") && (settings["bar"] == "fwd")){
          Model<FooForward, BarForward> model = Model<FooForward, BarForward>(i);
          return model;
        }
        else if ((settings["foo"] == "fwd") && (settings["bar"] == "bwd")){
          Model<FooForward, BarBackward> model = Model<FooForward, BarBackward>(i);
          return model;
        }
        else if ((settings["foo"] == "bwd") && (settings["bar"] == "fwd")){
          Model<FooBackward, BarForward> model = Model<FooBackward, BarForward>(i);
          return model;
        }
        else// ((settings["foo"] == "bwd") && (settings["bar"] == "bwd"))
        {
          Model<FooBackward, BarBackward> model = Model<FooBackward, BarBackward>(i);
          return model;
        }
    }
};
```

But now you'll need a visitor to actually invoke the required `solve()` method:

```
auto model { Factory::createModel( settings , 1 ) };

boost::apply_visitor( [ ]( auto & m ){ m.solve(); } , model );
//     > FooForward::compute()
//     > BarBackward::eval()
```

[Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec3579e3d2240288)

Also without resorting to some kind of template metaprogramming this soon will be hard to mantain if you keep adding different `Foo` and `Bar` implementations.

---

***Original answer:***

Maybe you could use a static template variable and a simple function:

```
std::map< std::string , std::string > settings
{
    { "foo" , "fwd" } ,
    { "bar" , "bwd" }
};

template< typename F , typename B>
static Model< F , B > m( 1 );

void solve()
{
    if ((settings["foo"] == "fwd") && (settings["bar"] == "fwd")){
      m<FooForward, BarForward>.solve();
    }
    else if ((settings["foo"] == "fwd") && (settings["bar"] == "bwd")){
      m<FooForward, BarBackward>.solve();
    }
    else if ((settings["foo"] == "bwd") && (settings["bar"] == "fwd")){
      m<FooBackward, BarForward>.solve();
    }
    else// ((settings["foo"] == "bwd") && (settings["bar"] == "bwd"))
    {
      m<FooBackward, BarBackward>.solve();
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Load settings somehow

    solve(); // > FooForward::compute()
             // > BarBackward::eval()

}
```

[Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6621fff25b993b34)

You can hide these things in a anonymous namespace in the translation unity where you use them for better encapsulation and avoid using a factory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'm going to try this and let you know. As for the maintenance part, that's what I was afraid of. I currently have more than 2 implementations for `Foo` and `Bar` and more than 2 members in `Model` which increases a lot the number of possible combinations. Do you think some kind of template metaprogramming could help me handle all the combinations or is it better to rethink my design ?